# PHP mail not working with "to" variable but works when emails are written as a string

Tags: php, email

I want to send an email to a list of users from a database.

This is not working:

```
$to = 'mail1@domain.com,mail2@domain.com';
mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);
```

But this works:

```
mail('mail1@domain.com,mail2@domain.com',$subject,$content,$headers);
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you get any errors? That's pretty much the way the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) shows. Can you test it with a space after the `,`? (just to make sure)

Comment: That code works when I test it.

Comment: Could be something on server?

Comment: @RodolfoAwenyddLunaBernal does `$to` and `mail(...)` happen on consecutive lines like described above? Try dumping `$to` right before the mail: `print_r($to)` and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that your headers are not using linefeed code or using them incorrectly. The correct usage is `"\r\n"` with double quotes.
Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
See Example #4 Sending HTML email.
I doubt that a space inbetween the emails addresses matters, but maybe to be 100% RFC compliant you have to have that space.

> The formatting of this string must comply with » RFC 2822. Some
>   examples are:

```
user@example.com 
user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com 
User <user@example.com> 
User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>
```